CSS divs infinite loop pacman effect
I have a .container and 6 divs inside. Each div has width: 30rem and height: 30rem


.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.container>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  box-shadow: rgba(24, 29, 38, 0.24) 0px 0px 0px, rgba(24, 29, 38, 0.08) 0px 0px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 0px;
  width: 25rem;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 25rem;
  height: 25rem;
}
<div class='container'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>



How can I make an animation where each child div is going to the left, like an infinite transform: translateX(-) but it gets out of the screen it will teleport to the right. Like in pacman where if you go to the one side you come back from the other. I want this effect, but being infinite.
Edit:
I used TanishqS idea to use splide but now i have a problem that the elements dont autoplay and they don't move. Here is the code
<Splide
               options={{
                type: 'slide',
                perPage: 2,
                drag: 'free',
                focus: 'center',
                autoplay: true,
                arrows: false,
                start: 4,
                pagination: false,
                wheel: true,
                interval: 3000,
                direction: 'rtl', // Set direction to right-to-left
              }}
            >
                <SplideSlide></SplideSlide>
                <SplideSlide></SplideSlide>
                <SplideSlide></SplideSlide>
                <SplideSlide></SplideSlide>
                <SplideSlide></SplideSlide>
            </Splide>


Edit2:
@TanishqS gave me the answer here is the code


import { AutoScroll } from "@splidejs/splide-extension-auto-scroll";


 <Splide
      className="splide"
      options={{
        type: "loop",
        pagination: false,
        wheel: true,
        direction: "ltr",
        interval: 3000,
        drag: "free",
        focus: "center",
        perPage: 5,
        autoplay: true,
        autoScroll: {
          speed: 1,
        },
        arrows: false,
        gap: '10px'
      }}
      extensions={{ AutoScroll }}
    >
                <SplideSlide></SplideSlide>
                <SplideSlide></SplideSlide>
                <SplideSlide></SplideSlide>
                <SplideSlide></SplideSlide>
                <SplideSlide></SplideSlide>
    </Splide>


This is a hard problem. My advice would be to see if there's a project on GitHub that can do this. What do you need this for? If no one else has created this, you might do well to change your UI design, or maybe try OGL/WebGL

Look into CSS animations.

Is the number of .container > div static?

I'd recommend you to use the Splide carousel library of js to achieve the "pacman" or more specifically, auto-scroll animation effect.
See this working example:


new Splide('.splide').mount(window.splide.Extensions);
.splide {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

.splide__slide {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
}
<div class="splide" role="group" aria-label="Splide Basic HTML Example" data-splide='{"type":"loop","perPage":3,"drag":"free","focus":"center","autoScroll":{"speed":1},"arrows":false,"pagination":false}'>
  <div class="splide__track">
    <ul class="splide__list">
      <li class="splide__slide">  </li>
      <li class="splide__slide">  </li>
      <li class="splide__slide">  </li>
      <li class="splide__slide">  </li>
      <li class="splide__slide">  </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.1.4/dist/js/splide.min.js
"></script>

<link href="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@4.1.4/dist/css/splide.min.css
" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide-extension-auto-scroll@0.5.3/dist/js/splide-extension-auto-scroll.min.js
"></script>



In ReactJS:
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Splide, SplideSlide } from "@splidejs/react-splide";
import "@splidejs/splide/css/core";
import "@splidejs/splide/css";
import { AutoScroll } from "@splidejs/splide-extension-auto-scroll";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Splide
      className="splide"
      options={{
        type: "loop",
        start: 5,
        pagination: false,
        wheel: true,
        direction: "rtl",
        interval: 3000,
        drag: "free",
        focus: "center",
        perPage: 5,
        autoplay: true,
        autoScroll: {
          speed: 1,
        },
        arrows: false,
        gap: "10px",
      }}
      extensions={{ AutoScroll }}
    >
      <SplideSlide className="custom-slide">A</SplideSlide>
      <SplideSlide className="custom-slide">B</SplideSlide>
      <SplideSlide className="custom-slide">C</SplideSlide>
      <SplideSlide className="custom-slide">D</SplideSlide>
      <SplideSlide className="custom-slide">E</SplideSlide>
    </Splide>
  );
}


Nice! But I think @OP wants that when the first div goes off the screen if immediately appears on the other side (without waiting for the ghosts). That's the Pac Man effect.
--- I could be wrong

@ControlAltDel is right, I want it to dont wait for the ghosts to look like continuous. How can I do that?

could you provide a visual example?

@TanishqS I want to replicate the effect from www.airtable.com from the divs that are under this paragraph Looking for inspiration?  Start with these resources.

@TanishqS Also the only thing that doesnt work with your answer, is that when the first div that gets out of view it waits for all the others to go out of view, instead of appearing from the left instantly.

I've altered the animation and used animation-delay,  see the updated answer.

@Tanishq what you've demoed is amazing! OP should accept your answer (IMO).

There are so many flaws in this answer. First, what if there are more count .container div elements? Secondly, when changing any parameter, for example animation-duration, you will have to manually change the entire code.

@TanishqS That didn't work, your answer makes them to move for a bit but then they just start again from the same start.

I edited my answer to contain the code of the child divs.

@zequuee1 can you explain what you mean by "start again from the same start"?

@TanishqS I am sorry if you couldn't understand what I wanted to say english isn't my primary language. I meant that the animation just resets and it starts again in a loop from the default start.

@zequuee1 I've edited my answer again, using a carousel library instead. Moreover, using the auto-scroll plugin to get the effect you want

@TanishqS I edited my question to contain the current code, that I am writing. How can I replicate your answer in my code?

I assume you are using react js?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
